# Saving Hebrew text to NSUserDefaults return strange encoding

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, encode, hebrew

I'm saving Hebrew text to NAMutableArray, then I save it to NSUserDefalts, this way:

```
numOfWallPosts++;
        NSString *tempKeyToStore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"wall_post_%d", numOfWallPosts]; // wall_post_%d

        NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [tempArray addObject:currentOwner];
        [tempArray addObject:currentTitle];
        [tempArray addObject:currentText];
        [tempArray addObject:currentDate];
        [tempArray addObject:currentTime];
        [tempArray addObject:currentImageURL];
        [tempArray addObject:currentWallID];


        [self.sharedPrefs setObject:tempArray forKey:tempKeyToStore];
        [self.sharedPrefs synchronize];
```

When I want to get the Hebrew text back I get text like this:

```
Wall messages: (
    "\U05de\U05e2\U05e8\U05db\U05ea",
    "\U05ea\U05e8\U05d2\U05d9\U05dc \U05e4\U05d9\U05e7\U05d5\U05d3 \U05d4\U05e2\U05d5\U05e8\U05e3",
    "\U05d0\U05d6\U05e2\U05e7\U05ea \U05ea\U05e8\U05d2\U05d5\U05dc \U05d1\U05e9\U05e2\U05d4 19:05",
    "27/05/13",
    "13:16",
    "http://blabla......",
    9
)
```

I tried to format the text in `UTF8String`, and with `NSUTF8StringEncoding` and I still get the text this way.

Can I save the text in proper way or encode it back to proper Hebrew?

**EDIT:** 
This is so strange, although the text saved strange, I pull it back and I get the text correctly.
But when I save them to NSUserDefaults, it show me this strange encoding.

```
NSString *tempKeyToStore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"wall_post_%d", indexPath.row];
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"\n\nWall messages: %@", [self.sharedPrefs objectForKey:tempKeyToStore]);

    tempArray = [self.sharedPrefs objectForKey:tempKeyToStore];
    NSString *tempOwner = [tempArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"\n\nOWNER: %@", tempOwner);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `NSLog(@"%@", ...)` to print the description of an *array* or *dictionary*, all non-ASCII characters are printed using a `\Unnnn` escape sequence:

```
NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"מערכת"];
NSLog(@"%@", a);
```

Output:

```
(
   "\U05de\U05e2\U05e8\U05db\U05ea"
)
```

(The reason is that the `description` method of `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`
uses the [Old-Style ASCII Property Lists](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/OldStylePlists/OldStylePLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001012-BBCBDBJE) format,
which, as the name indicates, allows only ASCII characters.)

If you print the description of a *string*, all characters are properly displayed:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [a objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Output:

```
מערכת
```

So this is only a display issue.

Comment: if i want to display the text correctly in nslog i need to encode the text to ascii?

Comment: @IdanMoshe: I would just use a loop to NSLog all entries in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like this:

```
NSString *someObject = //your object that needs decode
        NSString *decodedObject = [NSString
            stringWithCString:[someObject cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
            encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"decodedObject = %@", decodedObject);
```

**Edit:** There's probably something wrong in your code someplace else because this:

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tempArray addObject:@"בדיקה"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:tempArray forKey:@"test"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];    
    NSMutableArray *test2=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"test"];    
    NSLog(@"test2: %@",[test2 objectAtIndex:0]);
```

works fine.

Comment: You don't need to write the unicode inside the string. It should be something like `NSString *someObject = object;` I've edited the solution above.

Comment: I searched for hours to find a way to convert the encoding back from \U660 to ♠. Finally, this gave the insight I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, can you post the code behind sharedPrefs?

When i tried to save a simple hebrew to userdefault it worked just fine.

```
NSString *tempKeyToStore = @"KEY";

NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[tempArray addObject:@"שלום שלום"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:tempArray forKey:tempKeyToStore];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Read it later -

```
//
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSMutableArray *tempArray = [defaults objectForKey:@"KEY"];

for (NSString* str in tempArray)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", str);
}
```

Hope i helped..

Comment: I think it is only printing problem. Nothing to do with nsuserdefaults.

Comment: Try to print a simple array it will act the same