# How to convert string to utf8 encoding?

Tags: ios, objective-c, utf8-decode

I am reading my app directory like this

```
NSArray *pathss = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectorys = [pathss objectAtIndex:0];
NSError * error;
NSMutableArray * directoryContents =  [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                            contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectorys error:&error];
```

the output i get:

```
"Forms_formatted.pdf",
"fund con u\U0308u\U0308.pdf",
"hackermonthly-issue.pdf",
```

these are the files name. my question, how come i able to convert this name "fund con u\U0308u\U0308.pdf" to correct format. thanks in advance

Comment: There **is no problem**. It's just the (strange) way that NSArray uses to print non-ASCII characters. If you access the individual elements e.g. `directoryContents[1]` then everything will be OK. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774544/saving-hebrew-text-to-nsuserdefaults-return-strange-encoding.

Comment: actually this word is "fund con ü.pdf". I want it to print same instead of this "fund con u\U0308u\U0308.pdf".

Comment: And what output to you get for `NSLog(@"file=%@", directoryContents[1]);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the NSString to NSData with UTF-16 encoding, convert back to a NSString with UTF-8 encoding. 
It is probably UTF-16 big endian with no BOM. The character is not ASCII.

The character u\U0308 is not ASCII, it is a Combining Diacritical Mark ̈ü, the character is also known as double dot above, umlaut, Greek dialytika and double derivative. The \U0308 puts the umlaut above the u character.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
NSString *documentsDirectorys = [pathss objectAtIndex:0];
const char *documentsDirectoryCstring = [documentsDirectorys cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

EDIT:

```
const char *documentsDirectoryCstring = [documentsDirectorys cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: The u\U0308 character is not ASCII, it is a combining character, it can not be represented in ASCII. It is a UTF-16 combining character.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this. `NSLog` use description method of `NSArray` to print `NSArray` object, which deals with unicode characters differently than the description on objects its contains such as NSString objects. Or you can loop through the array and `NSLog` each item.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithCString:[[array description] cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding]);
```