# String Shown as Unicode - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When I print a String array to the log most of the Strings show up like they're suppose to, but sometimes the show like this:

```
\U200e\U05d3\U05d5\U05e8\U05d9\U05ea \U05dc\U05d5\U05d9\U200e
```

What is causing this problem?

Comment: It's not a problem. It's just a way of showing the string.

Comment: but why some of the string show like this "Hello" and some in unicode?

Comment: That's how Cocoa logging works. "Hello" is ASCII. Hebrew characters are not.

Comment: How can make it so hebrew characters show up as well?

Comment: Essentially the same issue as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774544/saving-hebrew-text-to-nsuserdefaults-return-strange-encoding.

Answer (score 0):

When you log an array with NSLog, or when you log an NSArray with `print`, you are relying on Cocoa's logging. It's very old so it represents a non-ASCII string by showing its codepoints.

If you don't like that, log with Swift's `print` and make sure you are logging a Swift Array, not an NSArray.

```
let s = "\u{200e}\u{05d3}\u{05d5}\u{05e8}\u{05d9}\u{05ea}"
NSLog("%@",[s])       // Cocoa is logging
print([s] as NSArray) // Cocoa is logging
print([s])            // Swift is logging
```