# Retrieve Hebrew in Ionic2 TypeScript application with http request from from mysqli php to MySql database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, utf-8, ionic2

I'm trying to figure out how to get `Hebrew` characters. In my `connection.php` I have  `$con->set_charset('utf8');`, so letters appears in input fields and recorded properly in `MySql` database with this `connection.php`:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-type: text/xhtml; charset=windows-1255');

$con = new mysqli('localhost:XXXX', 'user', 'password');
$con->set_charset('utf8');

if (!$con)
{
    echo 'Not Connected To Server';
}

if (!mysqli_select_db ($con, 'mydb'))
{
    echo 'Database Not Selected';
}
?>
```

But in several places, seems like, when I'm trying to get it from list, for example below `home.ts` `this.function();` `http` request, it appears this way:

[image]

```
 function() {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      let postParams = '&user=' + this.user;
      this.http.post(this.phpPath + "select.php", (postParams), options)
        .subscribe(data => {         
          var nmb = (data.text().split(".").length);
          let x = data.text().split(".");
          for (var i = 0; i < nmb; i++) {
            var c = x[i];          
              this.list.push({ id: i, name: this.s + c }, );
          }
        }, error => {
          console.log(error);
        });     
  }
```

particular`select.php` uses `connection.php`:

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';
$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["user"]);
$sql = "SELECT name FROM tab where user='".$user."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row["name"].'.';
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I've tried to add  `<meta charset="UTF-8">` to `home.html`, but `index.html` already contains it. And also I've tried to save `home.html` with notepad encoded with `UTF-8`, but nothing helps.

`header(‘Content-type: text/xhtml; charset=windows-1255’);` already in `connection.php`, and in result I have Hebrew characters in `MySql` database record from other `http` requests and `.php` back-end.

For example input in application:

[image]

or in MySql table:

[image]

But this does not affect button, as well as several other places in same application UI with same `connection.php`, like this one from particular code:

[image]

if there is no `header(‘Content-type: text/xhtml; charset=windows-1255’);` it looks this way:

[image]

or in application:

[image]

but it is different from:

[image]

I’m not quite understand, what I'm doing wrong and have to change with `XHTML`,  sending `UTF-8` and promising `windows-1255`, but I’ve tried return it differently, as a `json` from `select.php` with array `$myArray[] = $row;` as `let obj: MyObj = JSON.parse(data.text());` in `http` request.

In result console:

```
\u05d0\u05d1\u05d2\u05d3
```

And `object` is `undefined`

I found this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774544/saving-hebrew-text-to-nsuserdefaults-return-strange-encoding), which says that Old-Style `ASCII` Property Lists allows only `ASCII` characters, and I have print description of a string. Maybe it is a reason, but I’m not sure, how to do it in `Ionic2` `TypeScript`

**EDIT 1:**

I've edited `connection.php` with  `$con->set_charset('utf8mb4');` instead of `utf8`, and also I've used  `$con->query("SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci");`:

```
$con = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password');
$con->set_charset('utf8mb4');
$con->query("SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci");
```

`MySql` database row on server is `utf8_general_mysql500_ci`, which contains hebrew characters record and retrieves by request in other places of application.

I'm not sure, how to set `<meta charset=UTF-8>` for `Ionic2` `html` page, it is already in `<head>` of project `index.html`. With adding to `home.html` or any other page `<ion-header>`, nothing changes.

in case of `\u05d0\u05d1\u05d2\u05d3` now with `echo json_encode($myArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` seems like returns proper string with English `json` names, but hebrew still in `Mojibake`. Anyway, to avoid `Unicode codepoints`, in my case it is enough to get echo as `$row["name"].'.';` without array and object in `http` request. But I'm not sure, what to do with `Mojibake`

**EDIT 2:**

Show create table, `name` column contains hebrew:

```
CREATE TABLE `band` (
 `ID` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_general_mysql500_ci NOT NULL,
 `style` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_general_mysql500_ci NOT NULL,
 `member` text COLLATE utf8_general_mysql500_ci NOT NULL,
 `zone` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_general_mysql500_ci NOT NULL,
 `region` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_general_mysql500_ci NOT NULL,
 `website` varchar(800) COLLATE utf8_general_mysql500_ci NOT NULL,
 `image` varchar(2083) COLLATE utf8_general_mysql500_ci NOT NULL,
 `user` varchar(700) COLLATE utf8_general_mysql500_ci NOT NULL,
 `num` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_general_mysql500_ci NOT NULL,
 `registration` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_general_mysql500_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_mysql500_ci
```

**EDIT 3:**

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';   
$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["user"]);  
$sql = "SELECT name, HEX(name) AS hex_name FROM tab where user='".$user."'";  
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row["name"], ' ', $row["hex_name"], '.';
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}    
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

result:

[image]

**EDIT 4:**

result with text:

[image]

in text:

```
 ׳׳‘׳’׳“

׳׳•׳¨ ׳¢׳§׳™׳‘׳

׳׳׳•׳ ׳™ ׳™׳¦׳—׳§
```

copied from console:

[image]

in database:

[image]

as hebrew  text:

```
אבגד
אור עקיבא
אלוני יצחק
```

at the same time with another request in other page to same table and record, console:

[image]

in app:

[image]

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT name, HEX(name) AS hex_name FROM band where user='$user'";` then `echo $row["name"], '  ', $row["hex_name"], '.';`

Comment: @Rick James question edited, but Mojibake is still there with hex_name

Comment: I don't like it, but the `\u....` encoding may be the only solution.

Comment: @Rick James yes it changes method, but works. I have to mark your answer, because it contains all to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see at least 3 problems.

`\u05d0\u05d1\u05d2\u05d3` -- is using the Unicode codepoints.  Don't do that.  Use `json_encode(str, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)` to avoid it.

One image shows "Mojibake"; the other shows "black diamonds".  Both are discussed [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored).  `set_charset('utf8')` is only one of about 4 things that need to be consistent.

**Re Edit 3:**  `D790 D791 D792 D793` is the correct hex for utf8 encoding for `אבגד`.  So, the data is stored correctly.  But the data is not displayed correct (Mojibake).  Now, going through the link:

- The bytes to be stored need to be UTF-8-encoded. -- This is OK.
- The connection when INSERTing and SELECTing text needs to specify utf8 or utf8mb4. -- Provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'`
- The column needs to be declared CHARACTER SET utf8 (or utf8mb4). -- This is OK.
- HTML should start with `<meta charset=UTF-8>`. -- If your are displaying on a web page, see if it is set that way, either in the HTML or by configuring the browser.

But...  I am not satisfied that we are yet on the same page.  Mojibake should show `××‘×’×“`.  Can you copy and paste the output?  I can't do anything with that image.

Comment: Hello, thanks for feedback, I've edited my question, following guide by your answer, please check, I'm not sure what is missed there

Comment: @ViktorArv - Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for a table in question.  And `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` for something that is Mojibake.  (See my link for more discussion.)  The _collation_ (unicode_520 vs general_mysql500) should not matter for Hebrew, except for sorting -- both are character set utf8 or utf8mb4, hence able to encode Hebrew characters.

Comment: please check, added as edit 4 with image, text and database record. I have tried both  `$con->set_charset('utf8mb4'); ` and  `$con->set_charset('utf8'); ` as it shown above in edit 1, `<meta charset=UTF-8>` in `Ionic2`, and other requests and pages shows hebrew characters

Comment: @ViktorArv - Some pages work, some do not?  View > Source and see if the headers are different.  (Meanwhile, I have not figured out how to get from `אבגד` to ` ׳׳‘׳’׳“`.  The Gareshes worry me, but I don't know where they are coming from.)

Comment: I've added console from other page with php and request, where hebrew characters appears successfully, attempt to use the same described in question before edits.It is  same table, same record, request and php from working example was checked, but gives same result. Different pages, but same in html. should I call for ghostbusters...

Comment: @ViktorArv - This problem has slimed us.